# Change screen resolution info in Geckofx

Tags: c#, screen-resolution, xulrunner, geckofx

I am writing a browser application using C# Language and GeckoFX Browser library.
When i test the browser with whatismybrowser.com, it show my screen resolution (1366x768). I want to change this info like firefox responsiveUI tool.
I try the preference setting `devtools.responsiveUI.currentPreset` but it still not work.
I need help to change the screen resolution info, so any website will catch my custom screen resolution. Thanks!

*My custom browser*

[image: My custom browser]

*Firefox responsiveUI tool*

[image: Firefox responsiveUI tool]

Answer (score 1):

GeckoFX is using the same underlying component as the Firefox Browser. If you check Firefox, it also shows your computer screen. I don't think faking the screen resolution is possible.

You didn't mention your reason. If the reason is design related, you shouldn't have to bother with the screen size, the browser size is all that matters.